# Representing a strange number as a fraction

Tags: decimal-expansion

Can this decimal with special patterns be expressed as a fraction?  Is it a rational number?

$$0.101001000100001000001...$$

Where the number of zeros after every 1 is increased by 1.

Ty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an irrational number, since it does not have a periodic decimal expansion. Hence it cannot be expressed as a fraction of two integers.

Comment: Thanks man for the clarification!

Comment: are you really a Ph.D student at the age of 20?  Just wondering